# OCFS Configuration

Tags: ocfs2, rhel6

I'm setting up a Virtual Machine, and I'm trying to get OCFS to allow redundancy across two devices. It looks to be working in configuration, but it's not actually syncing the files across:

/etc/ocfs2/cluster.conf

```
cluster:
        node_count = 2
        name = vmcluster

node:
        ip_port = 7777
        ip_address = 198.18.0.25
        number = 1
        name = vm1
        cluster = vmcluster

node:
        ip_port = 7777
        ip_address = 198.18.0.26
        number = 2
        name = vm2
        cluster = vmcluster
```

/etc/sysconfig/o2cb

```
# O2CB_ENABLED: 'true' means to load the driver on boot.
O2CB_ENABLED=true

# O2CB_STACK: The name of the cluster stack backing O2CB.
O2CB_STACK=o2cb

# O2CB_BOOTCLUSTER: If not empty, the name of a cluster to start.
O2CB_BOOTCLUSTER=vmcluster

# O2CB_HEARTBEAT_THRESHOLD: Iterations before a node is considered dead.
O2CB_HEARTBEAT_THRESHOLD=

# O2CB_IDLE_TIMEOUT_MS: Time in ms before a network connection is considered dead.
O2CB_IDLE_TIMEOUT_MS=

# O2CB_KEEPALIVE_DELAY_MS: Max time in ms before a keepalive packet is sent
O2CB_KEEPALIVE_DELAY_MS=

# O2CB_RECONNECT_DELAY_MS: Min time in ms between connection attempts
O2CB_RECONNECT_DELAY_MS=
```

Status of OCFS Programs:

```
[root@vm1 ~]# /etc/init.d/ocfs2 status
Configured OCFS2 mountpoints:  /cluster1 /cluster2
Active OCFS2 mountpoints:  /cluster1 /cluster2

[root@vm1 ~]# /etc/init.d/o2cb status 
Driver for "configfs": Loaded
Filesystem "configfs": Mounted
Stack glue driver: Loaded
Stack plugin "o2cb": Loaded
Driver for "ocfs2_dlmfs": Loaded
Filesystem "ocfs2_dlmfs": Mounted
Checking O2CB cluster "vmcluster": Online
  Heartbeat dead threshold: 31
  Network idle timeout: 30000
  Network keepalive delay: 2000
  Network reconnect delay: 2000
  Heartbeat mode: Local
Checking O2CB heartbeat: Active
```

I see that the heartbeat mode says "Local". I've researched the documentation at http://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/dist/documentation/v1.6/ocfs2-1_6-usersguide.pdf and old tutorials at http://www.hbyconsultancy.com/blog/shared-ocfs2-partition-on-ubuntu-server-10-04-x64.html and other places. I am not seeing the whole picture it seems...

I'm using Oracle Linux 3.0.1, which is a modified version of RHEL6.

Comment: Is there any interesting in the log file `grep ocfs2 /var/log/messages | less`?

Answer (score 1):

This would be better left as a comment, but I do not have the option.  Anyway, regarding your ocfs2 configuration file, the node numbering starts at 0, not 1; so you would have nodes 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2.  I cannot say that will fix your issue, but nonetheless...

Comment: The PDF on oracle said it could be anything (they have 7, 6, and 10 for their example).